# Problem on installing phpmyadmin on centos 7

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, centos7

I have deleted my phpmyadmin by mistake while updating to php version 7.3
Now when i tried to install it back using this command `sudo yum install phpmyadmin` it is not installing I'm getting this response:

```
--> Processing Dependency: php-simplexml for package: phpMyAdmin49-4.9.3-1.el7.ius.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-recode for package: phpMyAdmin49-4.9.3-1.el7.ius.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: phpMyAdmin49-4.9.3-1.el7.ius.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:7.3.17-1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libonig.so.5()(64bit) for package: php-mbstring-7.3.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-recode.x86_64 0:7.3.17-1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: librecode.so.0()(64bit) for package: php-recode-7.3.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:7.3.17-1.el7.remi will be installed
---> Package phpMyAdmin49.noarch 0:4.9.3-1.el7.ius will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-zip for package: phpMyAdmin49-4.9.3-1.el7.ius.noarch
Package php73-common-7.3.16-1.el7.ius.x86_64 is obsoleted by php-common-7.3.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package oniguruma5.x86_64 0:6.9.4-1.el7.remi will be installed
---> Package phpMyAdmin49.noarch 0:4.9.3-1.el7.ius will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-zip for package: phpMyAdmin49-4.9.3-1.el7.ius.noarch
Package php73-common-7.3.16-1.el7.ius.x86_64 is obsoleted by php-common-7.3.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64 which is already installed
---> Package recode.x86_64 0:3.6-38.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: phpMyAdmin49-4.9.3-1.el7.ius.noarch (ius)
           Requires: php-zip
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-zip
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.1.el7_7.x86_64 (updates)
               php-zip
           Available: php-pecl-zip-1.18.1-1.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php-zip = 1:1.18.1-1.el7.remi.5.6
           Available: php-pecl-zip-1.18.1-1.el7.remi.7.3.x86_64 (remi-php73)
               php-zip = 1:1.18.1-1.el7.remi.7.3
           Available: php-pecl-zip-1.18.2-1.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php-zip = 1:1.18.2-1.el7.remi.5.6
           Available: php-pecl-zip-1.18.2-1.el7.remi.7.3.x86_64 (remi-php73)
               php-zip = 1:1.18.2-1.el7.remi.7.3
           Available: php72u-common-7.2.26-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Available: php72u-common-7.2.27-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Available: php72u-common-7.2.28-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Available: php73-common-7.3.14-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Available: php73-common-7.3.15-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Available: php73-common-7.3.16-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Installed: php-common-7.3.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php73)
               Not found
           Available: php-common-5.6.40-19.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               Not found
           Available: php-common-5.6.40-20.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               Not found
           Available: php-common-7.3.16-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

the php version was updated with no problems however the phpmyadmin it's not installing what can i do to get it back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't mixed so much PHP providers, especially; don't mix "IUS" and "Remi".

If you want PHP  7.3, only keep "remi-php73", and you can take phpMyAdmin (5.0.2) from "remi"

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73
yum-config-manager --disable remi-php56
yum-config-manager --disable ius
yum --enablerepo=remi install phpMyAdmin
```

Answer (score 1):

As Remi said, don't mix his repository with IUS.  Pick one or the other.  If you decide to go with IUS, we have phpMyAdmin49 and phpMyAdmin50 packages available.  Asking yum to install phpMyAdmin will likely result in it trying to install the EPEL phpMyAdmin package, which is stuck at version 4.4.x to remain compatible with stock PHP 5.4.x.